# DAX Syntax - if versus switch

Tags: dax, powerquery

Need help with the correct syntax.  I need to determine based on 3 columns (Year, Years of Service, Terminate)  if the years of service fall between the following criteria or the Terminate column has a date.

`IF(["#YearsofService"]=>2,"2+ Years" else "Less than 2 Years") else Terminate(has a date) is not null.`  This will be for an new column displaying the criteria text.

also tried Switch function.

`=SWITCH(TRUE()
 [#"#YearsofService"] >=2,"2 + Years" & [#"#YearsofService"] <2, "Less Than 2 Years",
 isblank([Term Date]), "Termed"
 )`

also tried:

`IF(ISBLANK([Term Date])=false, "Termed",IF([#"#YearsofService"] >=2,"2 + Years","Less Than 2 Years"))`

but does not like the If portion of statement

Comment: Are you in the Edit Query (with the Power Query steps listed on the right) or are you adding a DAX calculated column to an existing table? A screenshot would help. Those two spots have two separate languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SWITCH TRUE would be the best solution for this sort of multi-test requirement.  The sequence of tests after the TRUE is critical - DAX will stop evaluating after the first TRUE result is struck.  So here's my attempt:

`=SWITCH(TRUE()
, NOT(ISBLANK([Term Date])), "Termed" 
, [#YearsofService] >=2,"2 + Years"
, [#YearsofService] <2, "Less Than 2 Years"
 )`

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are only using two of the mentioned columns (Years of Service and Terminate). I guess the statement should look like this:

```
Result = IF(ISBLANK([Term Date]);IF([#"#YearsofService"]<2;"Less than 2 years";"More than 2 years");"Termed")
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I have tried it both ways with an IF statement or a Switch.

I need to verify if the Termed field (Date) contains a date if so then return the value of "Termed", else the years of service  > = 2 return the value of "2 + Years"  else,"Less Than 2 Years",

 So I need to look at the value of 2 different fields and see if it matches any of the above criteria and return the correct value statement.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it has issues with the ";"

Comment: here is my latest attempt.
     if([#"#YearsofService"]>=2) then "2 + Years" 
         else "Less Than 2 Years" 
        else [Term Date]<>Blank(),"Termed")

Comment: There's no "then" or "else" in DAX. See the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634824.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The first part of my statement was return values on the first two parts of the statement:  if([#"#YearsofService"]>=2) then "2 + Years" else "Less Than 2 Years")  I just need to add the Term portion of the function.

Comment: Once again, there are no "else" or "then" keywords in DAX. Moreover, if you want to merge two strings (or cell values) use CONCATENATE function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634811.aspx

Comment: Turns out I am using M not DAX - I am creating this in Power  BI Desktop.

Comment: How do I include an attachment/screenshot?

Comment: check out this webpage on if then else statements within Power Query:

[link](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/08/27/the-if-function-in-power-query/)

Comment: Well, you can use both M and DAX to create columns in PowerBI https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-calculated-columns/